# Control event in which a tap goes "through" an object?

Tags: ios

I am trying to achieve a certain behavior in which an object executes a method when a tap passes into the bounds of the object, and then another when the tap leaves its bounds. Since this is a difficult scenario to put into words, I drew a picture:

[image: Touch drag "through"]

Which type of ControlEvent is this, and if it doesn't exist, are there other accepted methods of getting this to work?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isnt any control event for this that i know of. You will have to implement this yourself. On the view controller (superview to your button) place the following methods, something like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
   // Touches began, check the position of my touch. Is it outside a button? 
   // note that in a BOOL
   ...
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // was my first touch on a button? if not, see if my current touch is inside
    // the button, note that
    ...
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Touch is ending, is my touch outside the button and did i cross through earlier?
    // If so, "drag through" event is successful
    ...
}
```

hope this helps